# How to code keyboard, LCD and its relative context in C

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to build an embedded application. Where, I have a keyboard interface and an LCD display interface. I am using 'C-Programming' for coding.

I have `Menu`, `Up`, `Down`, `Right`, `Left`, `Select` and `Exit` (7) keys.

Depending on context, I should display content on the LCD.

For example,

- When `Menu` key is pressed, I need to display MENU OPTIONS.
- In these MENU OPTIONS, depending on `Up`, `Down`, `Right` or `Left` key presses I need to navigate different options on LCD.
- If user selects "an option" from above context, then I need to display relative contents for that option.

So, there are many combinations possible. I know that, I can put enough conditional statements/switch cases to build my application; but, I am wondering if there is more elegant way of coding.

Tomorrow, if I get 20+ keys and 100+ different LCD context to be displayed on screen, then for sure, using conditional statements won't work (or become too tedious!)

Are there any good programming technique that can handle this?

Comment: Don't solve tomorrow's problem. It's good you think about today's efficiency though :-)

Comment: It sounds like your software could benefit from a rules engine.  Have a look here: https://www.clipsrules.net/

Comment: A long switch statement is not that bad. just get your data well represented in some data structure and `switch (key) { case UP: k_up(&data); break;  case DOWN: k_down(&data); break; /*...*/ }`

Comment: @RobertHarvey that looks like overkill for the OP's level.

Comment: You need a finite-state machine which can be implemented either with switch/case or function pointers.

Comment: 1. store your menu's as array of strings (preferably stored in program memory like `static const char *menu[]={ "entry1","entry2", ... , "" };`) and use for loops to display. 2. use global `int index` for navigating up/down just inc/dec , left/right either edit selected value or go through pages or scroll faster ... resulting in few lines of code and easy manageable menus

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions! Using below suggested code (psuedocode) from @masonthedev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like dimich stated... you can use finite-state machine to extend your application to handle additional keys and LCD contexts by adding more states and events to the transition table without cluttering your code with a bunch of conditional statements. This will make your code more modular and maintainable as your application grows.

Define the states, then events, then create transition table, then implement the fsm.

1. Define States: Identify the different states your application can be in. In your case, states might include "Main Menu," "Submenu 1," "Submenu 2," and so on. Each state corresponds to a specific LCD context.
2. Define Events: Identify the events or user inputs that can trigger state transitions. These events can be the key presses you mentioned (Menu, Up, Down, Right, Left, Select, Exit).
3. Create a State Transition Table: Build a table that maps the current state, the event, and the next state. This table will define how your application responds to user inputs in different states.
4. Implement the FSM: Write code that reads user input and updates the current state based on the transition table. This can be done using a switch-case statement or a lookup table.

Here's of an example of how you could implement this...

```
// Define states
enum State {
    MAIN_MENU,
    SUBMENU_1,
    // Add more states as needed
};

// Define events
enum Event {
    MENU_PRESSED,
    UP_PRESSED,
    DOWN_PRESSED,
    // Add more events as needed
};

// State transition table
const enum State transitionTable[NUM_STATES][NUM_EVENTS] = {
    // Define transitions based on the current state and event
    // For example: [MAIN_MENU][MENU_PRESSED] = SUBMENU_1
};

// Current state
enum State currentState = MAIN_MENU;

// Main application loop
while (1) {
    // Read user input (e.g., key presses)
    enum Event userEvent = readUserInput();

    // Update the current state based on the state transition table
    currentState = transitionTable[currentState][userEvent];

    // Update LCD display based on the current state
    updateLCD(currentState);
}
```

If you needed more context on fsm's, heres an article I found helpful...

https://flaviocopes.com/finite-state-machines/

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Your code suggestions helped!

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?